# Is this symbol $\supset\kern-1.7pt\rightarrow$ commonly used in mathematics?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

In Multidimensional Real Analysis I by J.J. Duistermaat and J.A.C. Kolk, the symbol $\supset\kern-1.7pt\rightarrow$ is commonly used. For example, $f: A\supset\kern-1.7pt\rightarrow B$ would mean a map from a subset of $A$ to $B$. Is this symbol only used in this book, or is this standard notation ?

Comment: I've never seen it before.

Comment: That would be a partial function. I've seen an arrow with vertical stroke for this ($A\rlap{\ \ |}\to B$, but nicer typeset)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ah, thanks, wikipedia uses: $A↛B$

Comment: Only place I have seen that notation is precisely that book.

Comment: I've used and seen being used ${\tiny \cup}\!\!\rightarrow$ for that, but never that symbol.